# How can I avoid 'Installation Failed' error when creating a Start Up Disk?

Tags: system-installation, live-usb, startup, iso

I want to create a Ubuntu 12.04 Live CD. So I open *Startup Disk Creator* in the Ubuntu Dash. I go through all of the settings, and then click 'Make Startup Disk'.

[image: Make Startup Disk]

Almost immediately I get a window that only says *'Installation Failed'*.

[image: Installation Failed]

I tried it again, and got the same result. I even downloaded a new copy of the .ISO file from the Ubuntu website. Sadly, the same thing happened.

How may I avoid this issue? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try clicking the Erase Disk button first. That will delete everything from that device, so make sure there is nothing important.

Comment: I did, several times. Thanks though.

Comment: can you tell what error's are coming

Answer (score 2):

Try formatting the USB stick with a FAT32 filesystem and try again. That should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

A possible reason for this error is the inability to access the ISO file. For instance, if the user can list the contents of the directory containing the ISO, but not read the file itself, Startup Disk Creator will let select the file, and then fail with "Installation failed." error.

It is surprising that this case was not handled by the tool, for example by showing a more descriptive error message.

Answer (score 0):

Format the drive to FAT 32 file system then use terminal first to get the correct device address like (`dev/sdb`)

To get all memory location addresses,run command: `df`

Get the correct location of flash drive and type following command:

```
sudo dd if=input.iso of=/dev/sdc
```

See this if you want more details

[How to create a bootable Ubuntu USB flash drive from terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/372607/how-to-create-a-bootable-ubuntu-usb-flash-drive-from-terminal)

Answer (score 0):

I faced many USB problem while making it bootable or during formatting. I had the same problem too. But in many cases, i solved just by restarting the system.

Remove USB, restart system , format it with FAT32 and then make it bootable.

Answer (score 0):

**The current Startup Disk Creator (0.3.2) in 16.04 LTS and later versions is cloning the iso file** to the USB drive or memory card. This process is very reliable. But there are several **bugs in the versions of the Startup Disk Creator** in previous versions of Ubuntu.

---

The cloning process needs no formatting. The process will overwrite whatever is written on the drive.

There are several tools that can do the same thing - clone the iso file to the USB drive or memory card also in previous versions of Ubuntu.

- **dd** is the classic cloning tool. It is very powerful but also dangerous, because it does what you tell it to do without any questions. If you tell it to wipe the family pictures ... and it is a minor typing error away. *dd* deserves the nick-name 'Data Destroyer'.
- **Disks** alias `gnome-disks` can 'restore' from the iso file to a USB pendrive or graphics card. It is a graphical tool, and there are checkpoints, where you can make sure, that you will write to the correct drive. *Disks* is included in standard Ubuntu and several of the Ubuntu flavours.
- **mkusb** can 'install' from the iso file to a USB pendrive or graphics card. It is a graphical tool, and there are checkpoints, where you can make sure, that you will write to the correct drive. [mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb) can be installed via a Launchpad PPA, ppa:mkusb/ppa.

---

**After installing Ubuntu**, you can use [mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb) to **wipe** the USB drive or memory card or **restore** it to a standard storage device.

Answer (score 0):

- Format the flash drive to FAT32 file system
- Then run command to find the name of flash drive eg./dev/sdb

  ```
  sudo fdisk -l

  ctrl + alt +t
  ```
- Then run the command

```
$sudo dd if=[filename.iso] of=[name of flash drive] bs=512k
```

- after completion start booting with it