# How to create a bootable Ubuntu USB flash drive from terminal?

Tags: command-line, system-installation, live-usb, portable

Is there any way to create a bootable Ubuntu USB flash drive from the terminal without using any third-party applications like *[YUMI](https://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/), [Unetbootin](https://unetbootin.github.io/), [Startup Disk Creator](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu)*,  etc.

I tried to create a bootable Ubuntu flash drive with `dd` method,

```
sudo umount /dev/sdb
sudo dd if=/path/to/ubuntu.iso of=/dev/sdb bs=1M
```

It creates files on the USB disk, but when I try to boot the USB disk it shows an `Operating System Not Found` error.

Comment: debian 11 here, this link helped : https://workaround.org/article/updating-the-bios-on-lenovo-laptops-from-linux-using-a-usb-flash-stick/ : bottom line is : install genisoimage, use geeltorito to generate an img from the iso, and then (my part) use cp to copy the img to the USB to create a bootable USB stick.

Comment: this is a very useful question. I liked it.

Answer (score 656, accepted):

You can use `dd`.

```
sudo umount /dev/sd<?><?>
```

where `<?><?>` is a letter followed by a number, look it up by running `lsblk`.

It will look something like

```
sdb      8:16   1  14.9G  0 disk 
├─sdb1   8:17   1   1.6G  0 part /media/username/usb volume name
└─sdb2   8:18   1   2.4M  0 part
```

I would dismount **sdb1**.

Then, next (this is a destructive command and wipes the entire USB drive with the contents of the iso, so be careful):

```
sudo dd bs=4M if=path/to/input.iso of=/dev/sd<?> conv=fdatasync  status=progress
```

where `input.iso` is the input file, and `/dev/sd<?>` is the USB device you're writing to (run `lsblk` to see all drives to find out what `<?>` is for your USB).

This method is fast and has never failed me.

---

EDIT: for those on a Mac ending up here, use lowercase for `bs=4m`:

```
sudo dd if=inputfile.img of=/dev/disk<?> bs=4m && sync
```

---

EDIT: If USB drive does not boot (this happened to me), it is because the target is a particular partition on the drive instead of the drive. So the target needs to be `/dev/sdc` and not `/dev/sdc` `<?>` For me it was `/dev/sdb`.

Reference: https://superuser.com/a/407327 and https://askubuntu.com/a/579615/669976

Comment: what will be the resulting format of the pendrive? I used the command showed above for Mac, and the resulting pendrive format was isofs. And that format wasn't readable by Mac OS X but it was readable by linux mint. Is there an argumento of dd to define the resulting format like fat32?

Comment: Can you see the contents of the usb drive after this operation ?

Comment: @ychaouche yes you will be able to see the content of the usb drive after.

Comment: `dd: invalid number: '4m'` -> replace by `4M`

Comment: "lsblk" is not installed on my MAC, "df -h" works.

Answer (score 130):

You're almost there with `dd`, but you're missing a step.

```
sudo umount /dev/sdX
sudo dd if=/path/to/ubuntu.iso of=/dev/sdX bs=4M && sync
```

where `sdX` is your usb device (this can be verified with `lsblk`).

The `sync` bit is important as `dd` can return before the write operation finishes.

Answer (score 105):

## Creating a bootable Ubuntu USB flash drive from terminal

- Place the `ubuntu.iso` file in any hard disk partition.
- Then mount the `ubuntu.iso` file with the below commands in terminal:

  ```
  sudo mkdir /media/iso/
  sudo mount -o loop /path/to/ubuntu.iso /media/iso
  ```
- Insert your USB flash drive. My drive is `/dev/sdd`. Here's a screenshot:

[image: GParted screenshot]

- Your drive may be automatically mounted inside `/media/`. Let's assume that it was mounted in `/media/xxx/`.
- Copy all files from `/media/iso/` to your mounted USB flash drive by running the below command (make sure to include the dot):

  ```
  cp -a /media/iso/. /media/xxx/
  ```
- Next, you need the `ldlinux.sys` file in your USB flash drive to make the USB *bootable*. My USB partition is `/dev/sdd1`; enter `lsblk` to see what's yours. Run the below commands:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install syslinux mtools
  sudo syslinux -s /dev/sdd1
  ```
- Navigate to the `/media/xxx` mount folder and rename the `isolinux` directory to `syslinux`. Then go into the renamed folder and rename the file `isolinux.cfg` to `syslinux.cfg`.
- Reboot your PC and change the boot order in BIOS to allow booting from a USB drive. Now your Ubuntu USB flash drive will boot and you can install it.

**This method will work for any Linux distribution, not only Ubuntu. You don't need to install any third party software to make a Linux USB flash drive**.

Comment: this is producing errors about not being able to create symlinks due to the destination being fat and the source apparently being some fs that supports symlinks

Comment: Is there a source for this explanation?

Answer (score 44):

You have two choices.

If you desire a graphical interface, use usb-creator (it is in the ubuntu repos)

[image]

If you want a command line tool, use dd

```
#Replace X accordingly in both commands

sudo umount /dev/sdX
sudo dd if=/path/to/ubuntu.iso of=/dev/sdbX bs=1M
```

Just be sure `/dev/sdX` is the flash drive you wish to use (it will destroy the data on the flash drive).

See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick for additional information.

Answer (score 36):

First, unmount the USB device and then use `lsblk` to verify the device.

Sometimes (usually older iso files) dd is not sufficient and the pendrive will not boot. In this case, you may need to install syslinux:

```
sudo apt-get install syslinux
```

and then run the following commands:

```
sudo mkfs -t vfat -I /dev/sdX
```

You want to run that last command to `/dev/sdX` and *not* `/dev/sdX1`.

Then, proceed with the following commands:

```
isohybrid /path/to/file.iso --entry 4 --type 0x1c
dd if='/path/to/file.iso' of=/dev/sdX bs=8M
```

or, to see progress of image write:

```
pv -tpreb /path/to/file.iso | dd of=/dev/sdX bs=8M
```

or instead of `dd`, you can use `cat` instead:

```
sudo -s
cat /path/to/file.iso > /dev/sdX
```

Rememeber to issue sync command to flush write cache

```
sync
```

[web.archive.org/web/20140327085331/https://tails.boum.org/doc/first_steps/installation/manual/linux/index.en.html](https://web.archive.org/web/20140327085331/https://tails.boum.org/doc/first_steps/installation/manual/linux/index.en.html)

Answer (score 26):

If by "third-party" you mean "GUI", [I suggest a lightweight script named bootiso](https://github.com/jsamr/bootiso) after [Avinash Raj](https://askubuntu.com/a/377561/276357) answer, because `dd` does not always work. The big plus is it's very secure (performs many security checks not to mess up with the system), easy to install and portable.

Also, `bootiso` will inspect the ISO file to choose from two modes: "image-copy" (`dd`) when the ISO file is hybrid (implies: USB boot friendly). And "mount-rsync" mode when ISO file is non-hybrid, in which case a SYSLINUX bootloader will be automatically installed if supported [[more details about install modes](https://jsamr.github.io/bootiso/#INSTALL_MODES)].

#### How to use it

First option, just provide the ISO as first argument and you'll be prompted to select a drive amongst a list extracted from `lsblk`:

```
bootiso myfile.iso
```

Or provide explicitly the USB device:

```
bootiso -d /dev/sde myfile.iso
```

#### Quick install

```
curl -L https://git.io/bootiso -O
chmod +x bootiso
sudo apt install wimtools
```

#### See it in action

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for thank you very much.

Comment: thanks for the install instructions.. made my life very easy.

Comment: Oh! My God! How is yours not the accepted answer? This tool tops whatever I have seen before! Thank you

Comment: This is the best answer. I can't belive this stuff is so hard …

Answer (score 9):

```
$ dd if=ubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso of=/dev/sdX bs=1MB
```

Don't use the path to bit.

1. Use the `cd` command to get to the folder that contains the .iso file
2. use the command `dd if=FILE NAME HERE.iso of=/dev/sdX bs=1MB`
3. Wait until the console output looks something like this:

   ```
   1028+1 records in
   1028+1 records out
   1028653056 bytes (1.0 GB) copied, 55.4844 s, 18.5 MB/s
   ```
4. Boot from the usb.

**Note: Make sure you write to the correct device a usb will not always be mounted at: `dev/sdX` where X can be any letter.**

Comment: Not sure why everyone leaves off `sudo` :) And `status=progress` is always welcome for the impatient

Answer (score 3):

### Title

> How to create a bootable Ubuntu USB flash drive from terminal?

There are built-in text mode tools, that you can run from a text screen or a terminal window. `dd` or `cp` or `cat` can be used, but they are not safe because they do what you tell them to do without any question, and a minor typing error is enough to overwrite a drive with valuable data.

Fortunately there are also safer text mode tools, but you have to install them.

- [**mkusb version 12 alias mkusb-dus**](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb) works also in text mode (not only in GUI mode).

Install mkusb via its PPA: If you run standard Ubuntu live, you need an extra instruction to get the repository Universe. (Kubuntu, Lubuntu ... Xubuntu have the repository Universe activated automatically.)

```
    sudo add-apt-repository universe  # only for standard Ubuntu

    sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mkusb/ppa  # and press Enter
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get install dus mkusb-nox usb-pack-efi
```

Installing this way will add not only `dus` and `mkusb-nox` but also some program packages that mkusb depends on. (If you try to install the whole mkusb program package, it also wants to bring some tools that need a graphic environment.)

- **If you want a small tool** or if you don't like PPAs or don't want any extra program packages, you can use [**mkusb-min**](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/min). This shellscript is very small compared to the other versions, yet it serves the purpose to wrap a safety belt around `dd`.

  ```
    $ wc mkusb-min
     208  736 5435 mkusb-min
  ```

It should be rather easy to see what the shellscript is doing simply by reading it in a text editor.

Download [mkusb-min from its Ubuntu help page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/min). Run it locally or install it into a directory in `PATH`.

- [**xorriso-dd-target**](https://dev.lovelyhq.com/libburnia/libisoburn/raw/master/xorriso-dd-target/xorriso-dd-target) is a new tool, intended to be uploaded to a Debian repository. The purpose is to make it very safe to create boot drives (USB pendrives or memory cards). A special feature is the **plug-in method** to identify the target device. The man page is available [here](https://dev.lovelyhq.com/libburnia/libisoburn/raw/master/xorriso-dd-target/xorriso-dd-target.1). In January 2020 there is not yet any installer, but you can copy and paste from the links above and install the shellscript and man page manually.
- Finally I want to mention [**bootiso**](https://github.com/jsamr/bootiso) which is described by its developer in another answer.

### Question

> Is there any way to create a bootable Ubuntu USB flash drive from the
> terminal without using any third-party applications like YUMI,
> Unetbootin, Startup Disk Creator, etc.

If we must look for text mode tools that are already installed in Ubuntu, I am afraid that there are no safe tools available. So in this case I can only suggest that you use `dd` or `cp` or `cat` according to many of the other answers here. But please **check and double-check that you are really pointing to the intended target device** before pressing the Enter key.

(By the way, the Ubuntu Startup Disk Creator belongs to Ubuntu (is not third party), but it needs a graphical desktop environment or at least a graphical window manager.)