# How do I burn a bootable cd on Fedora

Tags: system-installation

I have a fedora system I have download ubuntu I want to write the iso image to a blamk cd so I can install it on another (windows computer) thats sick (windows is corrupt)

What command line options should I use (on the fedora machine) to write a BOOTABLE
image to the cd so that when the windows box is booted it will see an ISO image and boot

I don't want simple answers.

Answer (score 0):

you can use "dd" command to create a bootable image

`# dd if=path/of/image.iso of=path/to/device`

but be careful with this command you can completely wipe you entire hard disk you you are not careful

double check the path after the  "of" part

Comment: but it can't worked for me see http://askubuntu.com/questions/372607/how-to-create-a-bootable-ubuntu-usb-flash-drive-from-terminal

Comment: actually it works! it works in the background you have to wait a bit longer till the prompt appears again

Comment: it creates files on the disk.But the disk created was doesn't able to boot.