# SD Card Not Recognized as Bootable

Tags: boot, sd-card

I went to the BIOS of my Asus S550 CM , Switched on CSM. I have a light weight version of Linux copied to a 16 GB SD Card.

No where in the BIOS the SD Card is recognized as a bootable device.

How can I make the BIOS recognize the SD Card as Bootable. Is there any requirements for a disk to be recognized as bootable. I have the DVD ROM appearing there even when its empty or there is no botable disk in there.

Comment: This depends on two things: either your `BIOS` can't boot off an SD card, in this case you'll have to replace your motherboard. Or your SD card is not set to be bootable. To help determine which of the two cases are present in your situation please post the full output of `sudo fdisk -l /dev/<your SD card>`.

Comment: Hi there.. how can i get that same infomation in Windows8

Comment: A few computers can boot from the built-in card reader. More (but not all) computers can boot from separate card readers/adapters, that are connected via USB. Some computers can boot from some card readers/adapters, other computers can boot from other card readers/adapters. They usually can read and write data, but obviously the booting ability is haphazard (probably due to lack of a strict standard).

Answer (score 1):

When you have an image of a Linux installation, e.g. an .iso file, you can copy it to a sd card using [`dd`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dd).

An example of dd usage:

```
dd if=/path/to/linux.iso of=/dev/sdx bs=4M
```

Where `if` is the path to the image, `of` is the path to the sd card and `bs` is the block size.

If you want to keep track of the progress you can use [`pv`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pv), For an accurate progress you've to give the size of the image.

```
dd if=/path/to/linux.iso | pv -s 2G | dd of=/deb/sdx
```

Now it should appear in the list of bootable media.

Comment: to see progress  `sudo dd if=/tmp/ubuntu-18.04.iso  of=/dev/sdc   status=progress`

Answer (score 0):

you can use (`unetbootin`) program for make a usb drive bootable.

Comment: I recommend expanding this answer to explain exactly what to do and/or how Unetbootin is applicable to the specific situation here.

Comment: I tried using unetbootin... it crashes while creating persistance...

Answer (score 0):

It seems error with the bootable device you made. Try this once more to get into the right way.

```
$ sudo mkfs.vfat -F32 /dev/sdx /* Formating the card */    

$ sudo mount ubuntu.iso /mnt  /* Mounting the iso image */    

$ sudo cp -rvf /mnt/* /SD_CardMountPoint /* Copying contents to card */    

rename isolinux folder into syslinux    

rename syslinux/isolinux.cfg to syslinux/syslinux.cfg    

rename syslinux/isolinux.bin to syslinux/syslinux.bin    

$ syslinux -s /dev/sdx  /*rename sdx with your device*/
```

See also: 
http://noohonlinux.blogspot.in

[How to create a bootable Ubuntu USB flash drive from terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/372607/how-to-create-a-bootable-ubuntu-usb-flash-drive-from-terminal)