# How do I do a clean install

Tags: system-installation

I've been a user of version 12.04 for about 6 months with a dual boot system with Windows.  In an attempt to delete Windows, I made a mistake and needed to reformat the Hard Drive.  I had version 12.04 on a CD and tried to do a boot install.  It didn't work, probably because I needed the correct installer.  I found an old thumb drive with Ubuntu installed, and was able to load version 10.10, thinking that the update process would be easy.  Unfortunately, it wouldn't update because the support for that version ended last year. So I downloaded the current version 12.04.4 to both a DVD and to a thumb drive, but neither would install.  I tried to work with the terminal function, but have not been able to figure out the correct syntax.  Help.  Should I reformat the drive, if so, How? Or is there another way to install version 12.04 that I haven't tried?

Ken

Answer (score 0):

From a Windows machine you can download and run the USB installer recommend by Ubuntu [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows). You will also need the .iso file for your machine from ubuntu [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop). Once you have the .iso installed onto your USB pendrive (should be at least 4GB), you can configure the BIOS of your computer to boot from a USB drive and install Ubuntu fresh onto the machine. Hope this helps!

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have Windows installed anymore. After I formatted my drive, I was able to install 10.10, but could not upgrade from there.  There seem to be plenty of ways to upgrade from a Windows system, but how do I upgrade from an outdated Ubuntu system?

Comment: Sorry - I misunderstood your question then. In that case, what @Woodworker78 is saying is correct. Install gparted (sudo apt-get install gparted) and see this question for instructions to make the USB drive bootable: http://askubuntu.com/questions/372607/how-to-create-a-bootable-ubuntu-usb-flash-drive-from-terminal

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I was wrong trying to create the bootable USB drive on my computer with the outdated Ubuntu system.  When I created it on my Windows desktop, it booted immediately on my netbook, and is currently installing version 12.04

Answer (score 0):

Even from an outdated ubuntu system you can download the iso and save to your computer, then you need to create a usb installer to make a bootable usb drive.  It's pretty easy, and pretty much the same thing you would do in windows.  I also tried to save the iso directly to my usb and it didn't work.  Save to computer first, then create bootable usb.  Good luck!