# How would i go about manuall recreating the process that unetbootin uses to create a bootable USB?

Tags: grub2, unetbootin

Would i simply create a bootable grub install and copy the files from the iso over, then edit the commands as needed?

Comment: Reading the source code would give you the exact idea. Do `apt-get source unetbootin` to get the source-code.

Comment: @Jobin good idea but it's tough to read source codes. I still didn't manage myself to understand pidgin sources.

Comment: How to create a bootable USB from terminal: http://askubuntu.com/questions/372607/how-to-create-a-bootable-ubuntu-usb-flash-drive-from-terminal