# Having trouble booting to USB to install Ubuntu

Tags: boot, usb

Hi I have a an Acer Aspire 5253-BZ660 running Windows 7 and I'm trying to install Ubuntu from USB. I copied the .ISO file to the USB. I have also gone into the BIOS and set it to boot to USB first. I've also disabled QuickBoot and Enabled F12 for Boot Options. When it boots, I hit F12. I'll select the USB I want to boot from and the computer will then start loading Windows; no error or anything. I even tried converting the .ISO to .IMG and it still didn't work. Is there something I'm doing wrong? I've checked other forums and none of those seem to help. I'd appreciate any advice.

Comment: See this article: https://askubuntu.com/questions/372607/how-to-create-a-bootable-ubuntu-usb-flash-drive-from-terminal

Answer (score 2):

Simply copying over the iso to the usb doesn't make it bootable. You need to use an application like [pendrivelinux](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/) or [unetbootin](http://sourceforge.net/projects/unetbootin/) to make a bootable USB.

These tools extract the individual files from the iso and copy them to the USB and then overwrite the bootloader of the usb itself, thus making it bootable.

**The above activity will erase all data from your USB drive. backup the data from the usb**

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem but i fix it by this program  [Universal USB Installer](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/)

and remember to make the boot from external device enable some laptop need this option like my laptop.... :)

Answer (score 0):

I had a moment in life where my both PC and notebook OS were not booting and found an easy solution for my problem.

If you have root on your Android phone, get an app called "DriveDroid" from the Play Store. It can boot as USB or CD/DVD device, depends on your setup.

Then add from storage, or download from app directly the Ubuntu .iso you want and mount it.

Connect the phone to notebook/pc and let it boot *check bios* from external device.

Problem solved.

**DriveDroid "how to"**

1. After you open the app go through the short setup and try to pick the most common options, nothing fancy.
2. On main screen oress the + icon on the bottom and select what you want to do, either download .iso straight from the app or if you copied it on your storage from PC
   just select the .iso from the storage.
3. and most important one: there is a strange way of mounting the .iso so i made few screenshots to guide you guys on it.

**1st - After adding the .iso to DriveDroid, click on the dots next to the target.**  [image: Click on the dots]

**A menu will pop up, follow my screenshoots and press the first "dot" as writable.
Window will close and app will return back to the main screen.**
[image]

**Do the same for the next mount point...**
[image]

**to get the final setup looking like this:**
[image]

Now you are ready to connect your phone via USB to your PC/Notebook and power it on.
It should boot to Ubuntu straight away. If not, check your BIOS/UEFI settings and let the machine boot from "External Device" or "USB" first.

I hope this can help! Best regards from Croatia