# USB Boot Issues

Tags: usb, asus

I'm having issues creating a bootable usb drive. When I enter my boot menu and select my USB drive it does nothing. I've tried re-installing ubuntu on the drive many times and still nothing. I'm using an asus laptop model number Q302LA and my usb is a 256gb pny flash drive model number p-fd256tbop-ge. Thank you in advance for your responses.

Comment: Did you turn off secure boot?  Not UEFI mode itself, just the secure boot part, might help.

Answer (score 1):

Try these:

- Redownload the ISO, as it could be corrupt
- (If you're on Windows) Try use a program such as Universal USB Installer
- Try use UNetbootin (Windows, Mac and Linux)

It could be something to do with UEFI; if so I'm no help there as I don't have a UEFI machine.

Comment: I tried all of the above there, still no result.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that your USB Stick is too large with 256 GB of storage, and "corrupted" from creating a bootable image. Normal people have USB with 8, 16 or max 32 GB, or DVD's of 4.7 GB ;)

I have one suggestion on that issue: I boot my Ubuntu Live CD from my phone via DriveDroid app. You can get it for Android and iPhone and it mounts via cable all ISO's except Windows images. Check the link for more detailed description and report if it helps you. Best regards!

[Booting via Phone](https://askubuntu.com/a/547379/346680)

Comment: I have a encrypted Note 4, will I still be able to do that with it encrypted?

Comment: Give it a try, put ISO on SD card, install the APK and boot your machine from external device. EDIT: But run the DriveDroid SETUP first, this is important. Report if you have any issues!

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.softwarebakery.drivedroid&hl=en

Comment: That excellent I will try this. I'm going to close this question I answered it myself. I posted another one regarding drivers and wifi if you get a chance check on it if you wouldn't mind.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was I have UEFI, I had to play around in the BIOS settings to get it to properly boot. I turned off secure and fast boot. It won't allow me to set my USB as my default boot so I will have to do that manually but that's no big deal. Thank you to all who helped on this question. Very much appreciated.