# Restart loop, before I get to grub

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi

I couldn't boot my computer today, for no explicable reason (as I in I didn't install anything, play around with any settings or anything - and computer was seemingly fine when I turned it off).

I can access the bios - but it seems the computer continually restarts itself, and before I can get to the grub menu.

I've stumbled across this: [Interrupted upgrade, now boot loop, restarts before Grub](https://askubuntu.com/questions/553733/interrupted-upgrade-now-boot-loop-restarts-before-grub), but I wasn't upgrading or anything  and I actually can't even boot from a live usb. (Still does the reboot loop)

Does anyone have any ideas, or is my computer stuffed?

[Interrupted upgrade, now boot loop, restarts before Grub](https://askubuntu.com/questions/553733/interrupted-upgrade-now-boot-loop-restarts-before-grub)

Comment: i'd check your hardware first; before getting to checking OS.  boot a live distro (image/iso, ubuntu install disk/thumb-drive) & do a memory test. some bios can perform this; next look at HDD health (smartctl, hdsentinel or whatever you prefer) which again is from live image. OR you could just run the live distro to ensure hardware is ok, etc.  before moving to validating OS.   ps: i commonly support hardware issues; which is probably why i blame/check hardware first...

Comment: Guiverc's hardware tests are worth doing. Also, please run the [Boot Repair utility](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) and select the "Create BootInfo Summary" option. (*DO NOT* click "Recommended Repair!") When asked whether to upload the report, click "Yes," and then post the URL provided here. This will give us more details about your configuration, which might provide a helpful clue. If you see messages just before the unwanted restart, what they are might be helpful, too. There's a small chance that my [rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) will get the system booting.

Comment: Thanks guiverc and Rod - boot repair utility was actually my first plan of attack - issue is, I can't actually even start a live distro (reboot loop begins before live distro can start).. Will see what I can do within the bios itself ... but it's sounding like it could be a hardware problem. Cheers!

Comment: If you can access BIOS - you said you can - then what's preventing you from changing the order so it boots from the USB? It has nothing to do with the (installed) Grub, you need to boot the USB before that.

Comment: Thanks Michael, yeah tried that.  Perhaps I should have said I tried to the start in recovery mode first (...which requires grub), then additionally tried booting from USB (unsuccessfully).