# Ubuntu freezes at startup. no key will work at all

Tags: 14.04, boot

I have Ubuntu 14.04 everything has been fine. I was using terminal for little low level things and I closed terminal but it wouldn't open back up. I decided to restart but when trying to restart, unity wouldn't boot at all. I couldn't find this same issue anywhere.

I really don't know what to do in this case...

I took two videos of what happens when I boot normally (it hangs after splash) then a video where I can get to tty from recovery mode.

Here is the video when I boot normally.Trying to boot normally: 
https://youtu.be/ykWUgxhH3S4

Here is the video when I'm able to get to tty with a persistent error whenever I type a command.Trying to boot from recovery mode.: 
https://youtu.be/zJ1BnVnvk4w

Here is the boot log from boot-repair

http://paste.ubuntu.com/10628382/

Thank you for all the help!

Answer (score 2):

Please explain what you did with your system, and well describe your problem since this quite probably does no matter with boot loader thus cannot be repaired via boot repair.

My suspicion here is you have to reinstall ubuntu-desktop and unity, and perhaps need to change ownership of home directory in case it's accidently locked by privileged user. While with little useful information I can't decide. Read this post if useful: [Ubuntu 14.04 - How can I reinstall ubuntu desktop with a live CD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/595485/ubuntu-14-04-how-can-i-reinstall-ubuntu-desktop-with-a-live-cd)

If this couldn't fix your problem, provide additional information to well describe your problem. I'll try if I can help (cannot make any comment yet).

Comment: I didn't do anything to the system lately. Can't even remember the last time I installed a program. I was using the terminal to root my nexus 6. That was it. Nothing system level on my Ubuntu machine. I will try to reinstall Ubuntu-desktop and unity when I get home from work tonight and chown home folder. One thing I did do, in the folder where fastboot resides (from android SDK) I believe the folder is /etc I moved a recovery.IMG file there to try to adb push to my phone. Could that have screwed something up?  Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Ffej5647 Since you can log into tty mode the problem could be with your GUI environment (ubuntu-desktop, unity, and /home directory) instead of linux kernel nor boot loader. I've read this post about how to root android under ubuntu: http://www.rojtberg.net/668/how-to-root-android-using-ubuntu/ but I'm not sure what could corrupt system. But the most essential point is you need internet connection to enable all apt functionality to fix possible broken packages.