# I am not able to install ubuntu using usb?

Tags: 12.04, usb, live-usb

I downloaded ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS iso file from torrent( size 700+ MB)and copied it in the usb. Then I made my usb drive bootable by running command line instructions (since my GUI is not working) from [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/372607/how-to-create-a-bootable-ubuntu-usb-flash-drive-from-terminal)!
Still when I change the boot settings from BIOS and make USB drive bootable, I get the message " Media test failure, check cable" and "OS not found"? 
what am i doing wrong?

Comment: The link you posted doesn't point to a specific answer, but to a question with multi[le answers and commands. Which commands have you used? Any errors?

Comment: Go for the first answer by Avinash Raj.