# RedHat Live USB creation

Tags: 14.10

I am trying to install RedHat OS on my laptop. I tried to create live USB disc from .iso file in ubuntu 14.10 by using startup disk creator. But I am not able to select any other .iso file than ubuntu iso files. Is there a solution to create live USB of RedHat?

Comment: Install Unetbootin in Ubuntu.

Comment: UNetbootin does not support Red Hat ISO images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You make a live usb with dd

```
dd if=/path/to/image.iso of=/dev/device bs=1M
```

Adjust your path and device as needed.

See https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Installation_Guide/sect-making-usb-media.html for details

Comment: I have created Live USB using dd command. But when I reboot with that , RedHat is not getting loaded. But if I create Live USB for Ubuntu , I am able to see that while rebooting.

Comment: @Gokulram it sounds like a problem with RHEL. ask RHEL for support ;)

Comment: Thanks bodhi.zazen. It was the problem with RHEL version. I tried with other version. It worked.

Answer (score 1):

- Rename the file to one it does accept. It will probably only check the filename so rename it to one Ubuntu uses. But in case that does not work...
- you could use command line. The option to do this is with `dd`. See: [How to create a bootable Ubuntu USB flash drive from terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/372607/how-to-create-a-bootable-ubuntu-usb-flash-drive-from-terminal) Mind though to take special care about the device you do this on. If you make a mistake you can kill a disk you wanted to keep ;)