# try ubuntu without istallation on my iMac mid 2011

Tags: live-cd, macosx, apple

where can I download the correct file?
How can I put that in one USB or SD card?
I need to try it without install it on my HD.

Regards in advance.

Comment: Any modern Ubuntu ISO being also a live image, i.e. when it is booting, you will see an option like «Try ubuntu», or something alike. You can write it to a USB stick [with `dd` command](http://askubuntu.com/a/377561/266507) *(Mac has `dd` command, right?)*

Answer (score 1):

The file you get from http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop provides both installing and testing. Download Ubuntu 14.04. Then look [over here](https://www.maketecheasier.com/create-linux-live-usb-in-mac/) to learn how to create a live usb stick. Also, make sure to enable booting from usb in your bios settings in case it isn't set that way anyway.