# Installing XUbuntu with out a CD/DVD drive

Tags: system-installation, xubuntu, 15.04, tablet

How do I install XUbuntu on my Linx 10B Tablet? It has no CD/DVD drive, but I do have a Sandisk Cruzer Switch 16GB USB drive. I will be replacing Windows 10. I'll also download XUbuntu on a Windows 10 machine.

All help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a bootable Ubuntu USB flash drive from terminal?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/372607/how-to-create-a-bootable-ubuntu-usb-flash-drive-from-terminal)

Comment: @h0ch5tr4355 this is a duplicate alright, but not of that.

Comment: And I can't seem to find that duplicate, so I'll put an answer for now.

Answer (score 0):

There is a great little program called [Rufus](http://rufus.akeo.ie) that burns ISOs to USB sticks. First download Xubuntu, then use Rufus to burn the downloaded ISO to your USB drive. Once that's done, you just have to boot from it.

**(I know this question is a duplicate, but I can't seem to find the actual duplicate, so I'm putting this answer here for now. If anyone finds the duplicate, comment and I'll delete this answer)**