# Ubuntu USB stick for Chromebook

Tags: usb, google-chrome, chromebook, drive

I have searched and still can not figure out how to get Ubuntu installed onto a USB drive.
I've ran both the "s9yrd" and "tnyga" commands, but to no avail.
I either get a no such file directory or read only file system error message.
I read somewhere that I can just download the ubuntu.iso image straight to my usb drive and then load through legacy mode, but a bootloader was mentioned. What bootloader is needed? And is it just as simple as placing the .iso and bootloader on the usb and loading in legacy mode?

Comment: Your question is somewhat all over the place. Basically what you want is to have Ubuntu installed onto a USB stick and use it as if it was real environment. Correct ?

Comment: Correct. I had kde running along side chome os, but with a 16gb hdd I decided to delete it and opt for ubuntu on a usb drive. I've read a few pages that listed commands but none would work for me inside crouton I always got an error message.

Comment: Ah. That's a very decent idea. USB ,however isn't meant to be a permanent media, it's more for storage, so it may be slow. At least it was on my older computer. It has been a while but from what i recall, all you need to do is enable developer mode and boot from usb. As fir installation, id recommend doing that on another machine. Ubuntu is modular, and it's easy to move hard drives with Ubuntu from one computer to another

Comment: Everything is already enabled on my chromebook, like i stated I've already had a kde partition alongside chrome os. I know a lot of ppl are going the usb route so I'm assuming the speed is ok. I already have the .iso on my usb and I know how to boot in legacy mode and run form usb. I read in a forum elsewhere that a bootloader was needed on the usb alongside ubuntu. So that is what I'm unaware of at the moment. I need more time on linux systems, I am very much a noob, but enjoy the learning process and being in control.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/372607/how-to-create-a-bootable-ubuntu-usb-flash-drive-from-terminal/377561#377561

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest getting Linux Pen Drive. This will allow you to mount your iso to a usb. From there, you can install it to your computer provided it is selected in the boot options.

Here is the link

http://www.pendrivelinux.com/