# Ubuntu Installer formated my home partition, now what?

Tags: 16.04, system-installation, data-recovery

For a lot of years, I have always upgraded/reinstalled my linuxes formating the root partition ( / ), and mounting other as /home.

Today I try it again, but the Ubuntu installer formated both partitions!!!! :'(
I'm paranoid, so I tripe checked that "the format check wasn't selected", and the summary shows only one partition to be wiped.

Anyway, is there a good way to recover at least some of my files that are below the new /home partition?
I'm not using that computer anymore, until I fix that. But that partition has been partially written with new files (not much, I hope).

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu ?

Comment: The version is 16.04.1, and I install it over an Ubuntu with the same version (I wanted a cleaner root partition, not home :( ).

Comment: This might be related: http://askubuntu.com/a/795190/271