# Ubuntu 14.04 doesn't boot properly

Tags: boot

My Ubuntu 14.04 doesn't boot properly. When I power up my laptop I am presented to Grub menu (though I am able to boot from recovery mood but in this way laptop's performance gets compromised). If I choose *Ubuntu these characters : ^[[5~ fill a black screen in a rapid succession. Then comes a 'vibrating' Ubuntu logo with so many entries like,

```
*starting send an event to indicate plymouth is up [ok]
*starting read required files in advances [ok]
*stopping userspace bootsplash [ok]
....
```

and it goes for forever but if I press "Esc" before filling up my that black screen by ^[[5~ I am directed to my desktop.

What is the problem? How can I fix it? I just want my desktop after power up as before.

PS : Even worse LiveCD of Ubuntu 16.04 doesn't show welcome screen. It shows advanced screen where I have to choose language. Even after that I get "stdin : not a typewriter" error and a vibrating screen. In short, I am not able to boot from a LiveCD either. :'|

Comment: What software do you use for the liveCD creation. Is it a USB or a disc?

Comment: I used Brasero Disk Burner to burn the .iso image on a DVD.

Comment: here are the images http://i.stack.imgur.com/dXomR.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you try using USB stick and depending on distro, some software for writing the image to it. 
In ubuntu go for `Statup disc creator` or `unetbootin`.
You can also try the `dd` method(read from this [thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/372607/how-to-create-a-bootable-ubuntu-usb-flash-drive-from-terminal)).

`Startup disk creator` works with cd/dvd also so give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

I am grateful to everyone for their help and apologies for responding late.
Thanks friends!

**The problem was actually hardware related.** I had got **"STICKY KEYS"**. I changed my Laptop's keyboard and now everything is back to normal.
Thanks once again. :)