# Steps to install ubuntu on a dedicated usb drive permanently

Tags: usb, windows-10

Previously I had Ubuntu installed on my pc along with windows 10 and windows 7 and was using windows 7 boot manager instead of grub. But then after an update of windows 10 my Ubuntu crashed and refuses to load. Since i think this might have been caused by the Windows 10 interference I've decided to boot Ubuntu from a USB drive.
Since I am a beginner kindly explain the detailed procedure in creating the live image and clarify whether Ubuntu be able to access/modify contents of my hard drive.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can install ubuntu in a usb, with a persistence option, this mean that you can store information in the SO, that is in the usb....

**This is from windows...**
Check this link: [Create a Persistent Bootable Ubuntu USB Flash Drive](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/14912/create-a-persistent-bootable-ubuntu-usb-flash-drive/) 
A video: [How To Create A Persistent Bootable Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS USB Flash Drive [2014]](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q7ZXA2Zedko)

**This is from Linux**
link 1: [Creating a bootable Ubuntu USB flash drive from terminal](https://askubuntu.com/a/376430/541090)
link 2: [How to create a bootable USB stick on Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu)