# usb not working after running dd

Tags: usb, dd

I wanted to make a bootable USB stick so I ran:

```
sudo umount /dev/sdX 
sudo dd if=/path/to/ubuntu.iso of=/dev/sdX bs=4M && sync
```

as per [this answer.](https://askubuntu.com/a/579615/480844)

I wanted to format the USB so I can use it again, but I got this message from `gparted`:

[image]

If I select "Cancel", I get this:

[image]

with which I can't do anything. And if I select "Ignore" I get this message:

[image]

and after that I get this mess:

[image]

How can I get my USB back?

Answer (score 2):

After you connect the USB stick, make sure it is **not** mounted and in a terminal type:
`sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdX bs=1024 count=1 && sync`.
(sdX = USB stick letter)
This will delete both the master boot record and the partition table from your stick creating a completely new and unused USB stick.

Using `gparted` now, you can create a new partition table and reformat it.  If you want it to be readable by all operating systems, use FAT-32.

Answer (score 1):

well if you are using Gparted try to format into another format...you should try ntfs. If you mount Ubuntu installer on it, it probably keep the Ubuntu format. But you may want to use Terminal for format, but only if you are related to work on terminal...there is a tutorial here 
http://trastetes.blogspot.cl/2014/11/formatear-dispositivo-usb-desde.html

its in spanish...but you can search from every comand if you wanna do it

hope it help

open a Terminal 
1.- "sudo fdisk -l" ; this command is for list disk and select them to format 2.- it will show some like this "Disk /dev/sdc: 4009 MB, 4009754624 bytes" - 3.- Unmount the device with "umount /dev/sdc" ; "sdc" could be anything else, its the name of the device, and the adress may be other too - 
4.- To format (u will loose all the files on the device) "sudo mkfs.vfat -F 32 /dev/sdc -I" to format FAT 32.. the " -I" suffix at the end, is the comand for make a file system on the device". 
5.- "exit". Done. You can write mkfs on terminal to see the format you can give to the device

Comment: Hey, that actually did it! I think you should just post the steps used in your answer.

Comment: open a Terminal -1.- "sudo fdisk -l" ; this command is for list disk and select them to format - 2.- it will show some like this "Disk /dev/sdc: 4009 MB, 4009754624 bytes" - 3.- Unmount the device with "umount /dev/sdc" ; "sdc" could be anything else, its the name of the device, and the adress may be other too - 4.- To format (u will loose all the files on the device) "sudo mkfs.vfat -F 32 /dev/sdc -I" to format FAT 32.. the " -I" suffix at the end, is the comand for make a file system on the device". 5.- "exit". Done. You can write mkfs on terminal to see the format you can give to the device

Comment: @NicolasSobarzo Add that to your answer by editing it.

Comment: @KazWolfe Yes, that's why I said that he should include the relevant bits in his answer.

Comment: Sorry i'm new, in fact its my first day.

Answer (score 0):

Use gparted's `Device` tab to create a new partition.  It will prompt you that all data will be erased.  Choose the default `msdos` for the partition table type.  This will bring it back to the original partition table type.

The proceed to use the `Partition` tab to create the partitions you want.

Comment: I get the same messages as when I start `gparted` and can only ignore or cancel.