# Bootable USB stick for another computer that has no OS?

Tags: usb

When I boot I get the grub> command, where do I go from here?

Comment: Find a computer that has an OS! See http://askubuntu.com/questions/372607/how-to-create-a-bootable-ubuntu-usb-flash-drive-from-terminal

Comment: Does the USB stick have no O/S or does the other computer have no O/S? If the stick, probably easiest to rebuild the stick using Unetbootin from a Window machine, or mkusb or SDC if you use a Ubuntu machine. You could also drop the iso file onto the stick and modify grub, not so easy.

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal on your ubuntu system.

Type `df -h` This lists all your devices which are currently mounted to the file system.
Now connect your USB-Stick and run `df -h` again. The new device is your USB-Stick. The left column gives the device name of your USB-Stick; it will be listed as something like /dev/sdb

You now need to unmount your stick. Run `umount /dev/sdb1`, replacing sdd1 with whatever your USB-Sticks's device name is (including the partition number). If your USB-Stick shows up more than once in the output of `df` due to having multiple partitions on the SD card, you should unmount all of these partitions.

Next you can run this command:

```
sudo dd bs=4M if=/path/to/your/isofile.iso of=/dev/sdb
```

Remember to replace `/dev/sdb` with your actual device name.

Please note that block size set to 4M will work most of the time; if not, please try 1M, although this will take considerably longer.

The `dd` command does not give any information of its progress and so may appear to have frozen; it could take more than five minutes to finish writing to the stick. To see the progress of the copy operation you can run `sudo pkill -USR1 -n -x dd` in another terminal. The progress will be displayed in the original window and not the window with the pkill command; it may not display immediately, due to buffering.

Now plug in the stick at the computer, which have no OS. You can now boot from the stick.