# Start up disk creator can t load

Tags: 14.04, 17.04

I tried to open to create a new USB bootable device for ubuntu 17.04 , but I can t open the startup disk creator and it sends this error :

```
'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 3: invalid start byte
```

Can someone answer quick cause my pc is out of OS and its my only pc for work!!

xubuntu 14.04  /  ubuntu 17.04

Comment: A quick and dirty solution that I often use is to just `dd` the ISO to the flash drive

Comment: Try to use another program like etcher and download iso from internet

Comment: What do you mean with dd ?

Comment: See this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/372607/how-to-create-a-bootable-ubuntu-usb-flash-drive-from-terminal