# Can I create iso image from my current Ubuntu 16.04 including all the manually installed package?

Tags: iso

I see there are multiple same question like this but here I just want to confirm can I create an iso file from currently installed Ubuntu 16.04.1 with all the package I've installed? Also is it possible to also include the library installed in python virtualenvironment?

I have this tesseract-ocr library installed and other library that were not included when I first setting up Ubuntu 16.04.1, so is it possible to clone my current Ubuntu system and create an iso file from it? What are the current stable software that can do that specifically for Ubuntu 16.04.1

Thank you for the help

Comment: Eh, I mean you could use `dd` to create an IMG file, but that would only be useful for restoring to the same computer.

Comment: I don't want to restore to the same computer. I would like to make it as backup and install it on other computer with same setting, same library installed as the previous computer

Comment: yes, this is a duplicate question but here I just want to confirm if the iso file created also include all the library that I installed manually. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I had the same situation as yours. and I did the following:

1. Install Ubuntu 16.04 on USB flash drive (Consider the USB as if it is the hard drive).
2. Boot from the USB.
3. Do the changes you want. (Installing packages and changing settings.)
4. Boot back into the original system (Not the USB).
5. Backup the USB flash drive by creating bootable ISO image from USB.

Also, check to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/372607/how-to-create-a-bootable-ubuntu-usb-flash-drive-from-terminal) question for step No. 5

Answer (score 0):

Try [**LinuxRespin/Remastersys**](https://github.com/ch1x0r/LinuxRespin).  
It can be used to create live bootable ISO from your current installation of Ubuntu/Debian.

Guess that's what you need.