# Cannot install ubuntu Kylin 32bit on mini winpad laptop

Tags: boot

I got a winpad which is windows 10 32 bit installed 
Bom selection for windows 10 is forced on bios. Only 2 USB drives no cd disk drives.

I downloaded kylin ubuntu 32bit and tried using Refus , unibootin disk part by cmd to boot ubuntu by USB but it never boots I have checked my bios secure boot already disabled and quiet boot enabled tried disabling but doesn't make any sense fastboot enabled and
Disabled but no change

It doesn't boot at all please help me to install ubuntu to my winpad

Answer (score 1):

Now i ' m doing the same for a mediacom W700 winpad.
If you can' t boot at all probably is because you need a 64 bit system with a 32 bit boot/efi.
Usually efi has always bootx64.efi file but in some table.
Check the intel page of yours processor, are you sure it runs 32 bit system?
For boot with a linux system (or any system for example android) do this:

1. Download the iso, i' m trying lubuntu (lightweight version of Ubuntu) becasue the tablet has only 1GB of ram and so it isn' t really powerful.
2. (Optional) Make a backup of your tablet with [Macrium Reflect Free](https://www.macrium.com/reflectfree) or somehow, in case you run into some malfunction of the tablet with the new system. Personally i won' t do it.
3. Format an usb flash drive with the FAT32 mode.
4. Open the iso with archive manager and extract all the files in the usb. You will get an error about cannot copy symlink ignore it. Create the folder that you cannot copy.
   But with some distros it might not work. Is better follow this answer to create the bootable usb https://askubuntu.com/a/376430/799907 (the required a FAT32 formatted flash drive). 
   There this project which create automatically a bootable iso with many options and wi-fi, bluetooth audio drivers. https://linuxiumcomau.blogspot.com/2017/06/customizing-ubuntu-isos-documentation.html
5. Make the system bootable for the table. Simply download the [efi 32 bit](https://github.com/hirotakaster/baytail-bootia32.efi) 
   and add it to the folder with EFI/BOOT (everywhere you should be fine) in the usb flash drive.
6. Turn on the tablet in the bios menu (mine is got holding volume up) and choose boot from file. Choose the bootia32.efi file previoulsy added.
7. Install the system you will need a keyboard and a mouse. You can alternate them on your one usb free port (one is used for the usb flash drive, and you need 2 usb to usb micro obviously) or buy an OTG hub like [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00FGKXY9S). Be patient when you boot the tablet, it may need a little bit of time, don 't press any the buttons while waiting.
8. I installed the OS but i can' t use the touch.
9. Follow this question for have the touch enabled [Enable the touchscreen of a Mediacom WinPad W700](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1067640/enable-the-touchscreen-of-a-mediacom-winpad-w700)
10. For other hardware issue this question [Enable the speakers,microphone and camera](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1074574/enable-the-speakers-microphone-and-camera) (not solved yet).

I hope that they add support for table in the official release of the kernel.