# Enable the touchscreen of a Mediacom WinPad W700

Tags: kernel, touchscreen, tablet, firmware

This tablet runs Windows 10 by default, but I installed Lubuntu 18.04. I' m trying to use [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1049787/lenovo-ideapad-330-touchpad-not-working) question as a guide but my case is different.

An `ELAN` device is for a touchpad and every command don ' t return anything indeed. The command `sudo dmesg | grep i2c` returns:

```
[    3.211266] i2c /dev entries driver
[    3.328881] i2c_designware 80860F41:04: I2C bus managed by PUNIT
[   37.847473] axp20x-i2c i2c-INT33F4:00: AXP20x variant AXP288 found
[   37.872164] silead_ts i2c-MSSL1680:00: i2c-MSSL1680:00 supply vddio not found, using dummy regulator
[   37.872202] silead_ts i2c-MSSL1680:00: i2c-MSSL1680:00 supply avdd not found, using dummy regulator
[   37.872740] silead_ts i2c-MSSL1680:00: Silead chip ID: 0xB4820000
[   37.928036] axp20x-i2c i2c-INT33F4:00: AXP20X driver loaded
[   38.024519] silead_ts i2c-MSSL1680:00: Direct firmware load for silead/mssl1680.fw failed with error -2
[   38.024529] silead_ts i2c-MSSL1680:00: Firmware request error -2
[   38.027163] silead_ts: probe of i2c-MSSL1680:00 failed with error -2
[   39.030645] input: axp20x-pek as /devices/platform/80860F41:04/i2c-4/i2c-INT33F4:00/axp221-pek/input/input6
```

I discovered that the Mediacom drivers are the same as those for TrekStor, a company that also works with Mediacom, and found [this](https://github.com/onitake/gsl-firmware/tree/master/firmware/trekstor/surftab7new) wonderful project on github. Mediacom WinpadW700 corresponds at SurfTab wintron 7.0 (ST70416-6).

The project is about tablets and Ubuntu and states:

> This repository contains firmware images for the Silead touchscreen controllers in various tablet (and other) devices [. . .]
>
> The firmware files were extracted from Android and Windows device drivers, as published by device manufacturers. They are intended for people who prefer to replace the shipped operating system with a generic Linux distribution such as Debian or Ubuntu.

I think that I should use the `silead_ts.fw` file (that is the firmware for `gslx680-acpi` obtained from the `firmware.fw` that is the firmware extracted from the original drivers).

So the `silead_ts.fw` firmware is especially designed for my problem. How can I use it? This section from https://github.com/onitake/gsl-firmware#silead_ts should explain how do it:
 
i must edit the `drivers/platform/x86/silead_dmi.c` file in the source code. Then recompiling the kernel (with that file), and somewhere add the firmware which i referred in the modified file.

How can i recompile the kernel? I' m trying [this](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel) guide.

I used `apt-get source linux-headers-4.15.0-33-generic` and got the `linux-4.15` folder of 800 MB. That has the path `drivers/platform/x86/silead_dmi.c` in which i already made the `drivers/platform/x86/silead_dmi.c` file. Following the guide i used `apt-get source linux-image-$(uname -r)` and got the `linux-signed-4.15.0` folder of 118 kB.

Now using `fakeroot debian/rules editconfigs` I get an error:

```
dh editconfigs
dh: Unknown sequence editconfigs (choose from: binary binary-arch binary-indep build build-arch build-indep clean install install-arch install-indep)
debian/rules:35: recipe for target 'editconfigs' failed
make: *** [editconfigs] Error 2
```

How can I fix this error and recompile the kernel?

Comment: Hi. I received your link to this question in chat. I hope to have my first tablet running chrome OS with Ubuntu in a Linux Virtual Machine in a few months. Now my touchscreen experience is limited to android phones.

Comment: Hi. I checked the ubuntu touch page if i have an android phone not listed i can do something?

Comment: I've never used Ubuntu Touch. I've only used a cell phone with Android OS and Touch Screen. I plan on buying a Chromebook that runs Google OS called Chrome. They allow Linux to run on it through a virtual machine. In the virtual machine I plan on installing Ubuntu 16.04 LTS regular edition (not touch). I hope that clears things up.

Comment: My previous comment is not referred to the question just to be clear. As i said is a WinPad which used to run Windows 10.

Comment: Usually firmware files have to be placed in `/usr/lib/firmware/`

Comment: @mattia.b89 I updated the question

Comment: this may help you: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel

Comment: @mattia.b89 i get an error and i have some doubts to how properly recompile the kernel how explained in the updated question

Comment: Besides using `sudo acpidump | grep -C3 ELAN` you can try `sudo acpidump | grep -C3 -i ELAN` to filter on `elan` and `Elan` as well. The same holds true for your `dmesg | grep elan` use `dmesg | grep -i elan` instead. Also could you include the output from `xinput --list` in your question? I'd like to see if there is an entry for `ELAN Touchscreen id` there.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix after some time that i' ve done the question i discovered that elan is for the touchpad and i tried every commands that you' ve suggested without any result as i said in the updated question. I also added this link https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Calibrating_Touchscreen#Your_screen maybe using only xinput i can do it?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix xinput doesn' t detect the touchscreen so i can' t use it to calibrate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `silead_ts.fw` is for this deprecated project https://github.com/onitake/gslx680-acpi. 
You should use at least the https://github.com/onitake/gsl-firmware/blob/master/firmware/trekstor/surftab7new/firmware.fw, fimrware only extracted and not modified for the old project.

But you must use this https://github.com/onitake/gsl-firmware/blob/master/firmware/linux/silead/gsl1686-surftab-wintron70-st70416-6.fw ,put the file in `/lib/firmware/silead`(create the folder `silead`). Also made a copy with the name `mssl1680.fw` (backup firmware).

Now follow this guide for recompile the kernel https://debian-handbook.info/browse/squeeze/sect.kernel-compilation.html.
Use `apt-cache search ^linux-source` to find the source for the kernel (as the guide explains).

In the `silead_dmi.c` file add:

```
static const struct property_entry mediacom_w700_props[] = {
    PROPERTY_ENTRY_U32("touchscreen-size-x", 884),
    PROPERTY_ENTRY_U32("touchscreen-size-y", 632),
    PROPERTY_ENTRY_STRING("firmware-name",
                  "gsl1686-surftab-wintron70-st70416-6.fw"),
    PROPERTY_ENTRY_U32("silead,max-fingers", 10),
    PROPERTY_ENTRY_BOOL("silead,home-button"),
    { }
};
```

And most important in the DMI_MATCH add:

```
 {
        /* Mediacom WinPad 7.0 W700 */
        .driver_data = (void *)&surftab_wintron70_st70416_6_data,
        .matches = {
            DMI_MATCH(DMI_SYS_VENDOR, "MEDIACOM"),
                DMI_MATCH(DMI_PRODUCT_NAME, "WinPad 7 W10 - WPW700"),
        },
    },
```

Comment: Still camera and speakers not working but with onboard i finally have a complete and good touchscreen.

Comment: Please open a new question for the Camera and speakers with hardware ids and relevant dmesg, and we can all try to help!

Comment: I will i also have the microphone, grub menu (black screen but the countdown) and the windows button not working.

Comment: @GKoe https://askubuntu.com/questions/1074574/enable-the-speakers-microphone-and-camera

Comment: I fixed grub menu and righr click is perfect https://askubuntu.com/questions/1084212/onboard-hover-dwell-click-can-t-be-enabled/1088852#1088852.