# "Unknown sequence editconfigs" when trying to build a kernel

Tags: 18.04, kernel

I am following the instructions here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel

I ran

```
apt-get source linux-image-$(uname -r)
cd linux-signed-4.15.0
chmod a+x debian/rules
chmod a+x debian/scripts/*
chmod a+x debian/scripts/misc/*
fakeroot debian/rules clean
fakeroot debian/rules editconfigs
```

The output of the last command is

```
dh editconfigs
dh: Unknown sequence editconfigs (choose from: binary binary-arch binary-indep build build-arch build-indep clean install install-arch install-indep)
debian/rules:35: recipe for target 'editconfigs' failed
make: *** [editconfigs] Error 2
```

My `uname -r` is `4.15.0-34-generic`.

A possible duplicate is [Enable the touchscreen of a Mediacom WinPad W700](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1067640/enable-the-touchscreen-of-a-mediacom-winpad-w700), but the answer there does not address the "Unknown sequence editconfigs" message. Do the [BuildYourOwnKernel](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel) instructions need to be updated?

Answer (score 7):

It seems as if in 18.04 you need to run:

```
apt-get source linux-source
```

Instead of:

```
apt-get source linux-image-$(uname -r)
```

This should fix your problem.

Comment: Thanks. That downloaded something undesired called `linux-meta-4.15.0.34.36` but it got me on the right track. It seems the correct source package is `linux-source-4.15.0`. Alternatively, `sudo apt install linux-source` will download that source package to `/usr/src`.

Comment: Thank you guys for this, for 18.04 this seems to get me further than I was before