# Enable the speakers,microphone and camera

Tags: drivers, hardware, microphone, speakers, camera

I' m using a Mediacom W700 tablet (is like a SurfTab wintron 7.0 ST70416-6) with Lubuntu 18.04 (i also installed Ubuntu-dekstop but it has only 1 GB of ram).
How enable the speakers,microphone and camera?
 
Also the super (physical) button doesn' t work.
In hardinfo i see: `Audio: bytcr-rt5651 - bytcr-rt5651`.
So i used:

```
dmesg | grep bytcr
[   39.559314] bytcr_rt5651 bytcr_rt5651: quirk DMIC_MAP enabled
[   39.559319] bytcr_rt5651 bytcr_rt5651: quirk DMIC enabled
[   39.559322] bytcr_rt5651 bytcr_rt5651: quirk MCLK_EN enabled
[   39.581339] bytcr_rt5651 bytcr_rt5651: snd-soc-dummy-dai <-> media-cpu-dai mapping ok
[   39.581426] bytcr_rt5651 bytcr_rt5651: snd-soc-dummy-dai <-> deepbuffer-cpu-dai mapping ok
[   39.581557] bytcr_rt5651 bytcr_rt5651: rt5651-aif1 <-> ssp2-port mapping ok
[   39.581652] bytcr_rt5651 bytcr_rt5651: ASoC: no DMI vendor name!
[   39.583777] input: bytcr-rt5651 Headset as /devices/platform/80860F28:00/bytcr_rt5651/sound/card1/input6
```

I found [this](https://github.com/plbossart/UCM/tree/master/bytcr-rt5651) project on github, it seems perfect, it states:

> To enable UCM on RT5651 platforms,
>
> 1. copy directory to UCM location
>      sudo cp -rf ../bytcr-rt5651 /usr/share/alsa/ucm
> 2. update asound.state
>      sudo cp asound.state /var/lib/alsa
>
> UCM files should be detected and use with Pulseaudio 4.0 and above

I followed the step and i have `pulseaudio` above of 4.0.
If i run `sudo sh asound.state` in `/var/lib/alsa` i get:

```
asound.state: 1: asound.state: state.bytcrrt5651: not found
asound.state: 2: asound.state: control.1: not found
asound.state: 3: asound.state: iface: not found
asound.state: 4: asound.state: name: not found
asound.state: 5: asound.state: value: not found
asound.state: 6: asound.state: comment: not found
asound.state: 7: asound.state: access: not found
BOOLEAN: not found
asound.state: 9: asound.state: count: not found
asound.state: 10: asound.state: Syntax error: "}" unexpected
```

Other commands that may be useful:

```
aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: Audio [Intel HDMI/DP LPE Audio], device 0: HdmiLpeAudio [Intel HDMI/DP LPE Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: Audio [Intel HDMI/DP LPE Audio], device 1: HdmiLpeAudio [Intel HDMI/DP LPE Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: bytcrrt5651 [bytcr-rt5651], device 0: 1 []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: bytcrrt5651 [bytcr-rt5651], device 1: Deep-Buffer Audio (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

pulseaudio
E: [pulseaudio] pid.c: Daemon already running.
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: pa_pid_file_create() failed.
```

Not sound at all from the speakers and the headphones.

Comment: Maybe [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/426983/how-can-i-tell-if-im-using-alsa-or-pulse-audio-by-default-switching-to-i3-wm) about audio rendering in ubuntu may help.

Comment: @oscar1919 good to know but is some hardware/driver problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this project http://linuxiumcomau.blogspot.com/2017/06/customizing-ubuntu-isos-documentation.html you can find 6 files (4 scripts and 2 .deb) that are made for intel atom devices.
This files are for the bluetooth, wi-fi and audio. But you need the new kernel.
Wi-fi was already fine.

Kernel 4.18.15 audio working, pretty low max (speakers) volume, maybe is so by default.

Kernel 4.19 (not stable) also the bluetooth but i did not test it, now i have the stable kernel.

Comment: and the camera?