# Making bootable Windows Server 2016 installation USB stick

Tags: usb, windows

Is there an Ubuntu 16.04 counterpart to [these instructions](https://www.starwindsoftware.com/blog/how-to-create-bootable-windows-server-2016-usb-thumb-drive-for-installing-os) ? I need to create a bootable Windows Server 2016 USB drive; since it contains file larger than 2Gb, mkusb and similar tools, which try to format the target as FAT32, fail.

unetbootin refuses to accept NTFS-formatted USB drive, either.

As far as I understand, the problem is in finding Linux counterpart for "bootsect /nt60" command, to copy Bootmgr boot sector to target USB drive.

Is it possible without actually using a Windows computer?

Comment: I always use `dd`;-) See https://askubuntu.com/questions/372607/how-to-create-a-bootable-ubuntu-usb-flash-drive-from-terminal I would assume it does not matter to dd what the FS is and what the contents of the ISO are.

Answer (score 0):

Last time I had problems making USB with 64 bit Windows, the dd command helped:

First unmount the drive:

```
sudo umount /dev/sd<?>
```

Then write the iso to /dev/sd? drive, replace question mark with your usb drive letter from `lsblk` command.

```
sudo dd bs=4M if=input.iso of=/dev/sd<?> conv=fdatasync
```

Comment: Problem here is that `dd` will format the drive with the `udf` filesystem which doesn't seem to work on many laptops, and won't be recognized as a bootable device.