# ubuntu 19.10 installer USB boots on grub command line

Tags: system-installation, 19.10

I downloaded Ubuntu Desktop 19.10 full Image, I checked the image and it is correct, after that, I used the mintstick tool to copy the iso to the pendrive.

When I boot it from my new PC, I get a grub command line prompt¿

How can I do to boot in live CD Image?

Comment: ministick tool?? Copying t0 USB 0r making the USB bootable with the d0wnl0aded is0??

Comment: https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows and https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

**If you just want to create a bootable USB**

You can create a bootable usb with the regular tools available from command line in any distributions, like dd (substitute the path to your iso file and the path to the usb stick device file /dev/sd...)

```
sudo dd bs=8192 if=<path to iso> of=<path to usb device> conv=fdatasync  status=progress
```

See the similar question here: [How to create a bootable Ubuntu USB flash drive from terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/372607/how-to-create-a-bootable-ubuntu-usb-flash-drive-from-terminal)

**If you want to understand why it will not boot**

The process is explained here: [Why Doesn't a Bootable USB Boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1190764/why-doesnt-a-bootable-usb-boot/)